# Algebraic variety determined by closed points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am in the process of understanding the importance of the closed points of algebraic varieties (taking the scheme point of view). I ask myself the following question: if varieties $X$ and $Y$ over a field $k$ have closed points in bijection, then are ALL points of $X$ in bijection with the points of $Y$?.

Edit: I am only interested in *projective varieties.*

Comment: Do you really just want a set-theoretic bijection? It seems to me that all positive dimensional varieties are bijective to one another, so this isn't asking very much.

Comment: What Hoot said. But maybe the kind of statement you want to make is Hartshorne Proposition II.2.6.

Comment: I extend the comment of Nefertiti: you can consult the exercise 2.14 at the end of the section II.2.